# Three.js ColladaLoader "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, three.js, collada

I'm trying to repeat the kinematics example found here:

https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_collada_kinematics

If I use the collada provided in the example everything is fine. However, if I'm using my own collada, I'm getting the "length" error at line 138 (I'm using the exact same code for now):

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_loader_collada_kinematics.html

Anyone have an idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an answer I got on the Three.js github, my dae file does not contain any kinematic information (so tags like library_kinematics_models or library_kinematics_scenes) but just a simple armature (skeletal animation). I knew that, but I thought kinematic was to get access to joints and everything. So since it does not contain any animation data, <s>I'll only able to statically display it using Collada Loader.</s>

Edit: If the loader detects a skin and bone hierarchy, it returns the corresponding mesh as a [SkinnedMesh](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/objects/SkinnedMesh) under children (for me it was children[1]). This object has a [skeleton](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/objects/Skeleton) property that provides access to all bones.

After, you have to create an animation using the [Animation System](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/introduction/Animation-system).

For more information, you can refer to my [post](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/looking-for-a-way-to-animate-model-with-bones-and-joints-rotation-infos/1085/7) on the Three.js discourse.